# Overriding <tr> styling for <td> using sass

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap-3, sass

I'm currently working on a rails application where I want to highlight a row with a background colour, but in addition to that, within that row highlight a data cell with a different colour.

The problem I have is the styling for the td appears to be ignored. I just get the background colour for the whole row.

Inspecting the css client side it appears that the styling I apply for the td simply isn't there.

**The generated html**

```
<table id="project-table" class="table table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Row</th>
      <th>Fubar</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr class="clickable-row cheese">
      <td>Row 1</td>
      <td class="'wibble'">Hello World</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**The sass**

```
#project-table tbody tr.cheese {
  background-color: yellow;

  & td.wibble {
    background-color: blue;
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

ps: using bootstrap 3 but I don't think that's relevant to this issue, is it?

**UPDATE [SOLVED]**

Ok, it appears I was being blind and hadn't realised an extra set of double quotes were being generated for `class="'wibble'"` - thanks to @Dekel for quickly pointing that out, and allowing me to find the cause of the real issue.

To solve the issue of the generation of extra quotes I had to mark the output as html_safe:

```
<td<%= ((index == @project.active_pattern_index) ? ' class="wibble"' : '').html_safe %>>
  <%= pattern.row(count).instruction %>
</td>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `class` in the `td` tag should be `wibble` (and not `'wibble'`).

You should not use the single-quotes inside the class attribute classes: `''`

```
<table id="project-table" class="table table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Row</th>
      <th>Fubar</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr class="clickable-row cheese">
      <td>Row 1</td>
      <td class="wibble">Hello World</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: omg ... face palm... now I'm embarrassed ... ty for the extra pair of eyes, I needed them in this case ... I'm going to get another coffee :D. Though that is strange ... not sure where those double quotes are coming from ... I'm doing `<td<%= index == @project.active_pattern_index ? " class='wibble'" : '' %>><%= pattern.row(count).instruction %></td>`. But never mind I will figure it out ... you have put me on the right track. Thanks again!

Comment: Ok extra double quotes no longer generated ... had to mark output as html_safe and now it works.